# How do I get the selected rows from a v-data-table? (Vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I am using a v-data-table, with the option "show-select", which shows checkboxes behind every row, but I have no idea how to actually know which rows are checked and get their values...

This is the code

```
<v-data-table
   :headers="TopicHeaders"
   :items="allTopics"
   :search="searchTopics"
   show-select
   class="elevation-1"
   item-key="name"
></v-data-table>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The selected rows are bound to the value (`v-model`) of the datatable. This should be as simple as...

```
<v-data-table
   v-model="selected"
   :headers="TopicHeaders"
   :items="allTopics"
   :search="searchTopics"
   show-select
   class="elevation-1"
   item-key="name"
></v-data-table>
```

Now the checked rows are stored in the `selected` array. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323522/171456) for examples on how to manipulate the `selected` rows when using customized slots.

Answer (score -1):

They also gave your [answer](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#selectable-rows).

The **show-select** prop will render a checkbox in the default header to toggle all rows, and a checkbox for each default row.

You can **customize** these with the **slots** **header.data-table-select** and **item.data-table-select** respectively.

`slots` is doing this.

Every item in a `row` is pointing with this. You will be able to access this via `item.data-table-select`

For Example:

```
<template v-slot:top="t">
   {{ t.items[0].name }}
</template>
```

You will be able to access each row item like this. So, try to get a clear concept on `slot`

Edit based on your comment:

If you want to pass a row to the data then follow this code. It will help you I think.

```
<template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
  <v-button
     @click="editItem(item)"
  > Edit
  </v-button>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
   editItem (item) {
      console.log(item)
   }
}
</script>
```

If you want to put any data from table to another variable then use a `method` like the above.

Comment: I'm quite a begginer at vuetify, could you explain how I would then pass those values to a variable defined in the <script> area ?

Comment: Have you seen their example clearly? Without data you will not see anything in the table. With your data the table will create automatically. Click on ```<>``` and see two parts: ```Template``` and ```script```

Comment: My problem is not with getting the data into the table, but with retrieving only the selected rows and storing them somewhere else. I want to select some rows -> pass the selected row values to a variable.

Comment: The documentation mentioned that ``` item.data-table-select``` thus you will get the selected item. Try and try.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand better how slots work, thank you. How would I do a @click on the item.data-table-select? I don't want to introduce a new button, I just want to add an event to the checkboxes

Comment: I showed a button as example. When you will check a checkbox it will automatically identify the item. I think if you take a pen and notepad and write it then it will be more clear.

Comment: I've been on this for hours, I just don't understand how you set up an event to pass the item when the checkbox is checked...

Comment: ```<template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }" @click="editItem(item)">
</template>``` try with this.

Comment: Didn't work, the first one with the button did tho...but i dont want a button

Comment: You have an array ```selected```. Print that in template like this. ```{{ selected }}```

Comment: Didn't get you solution?

Comment: I had to find another way to do it, but thank you anyway